# Is this possible to do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is this loop possible to do in JavaScript? The result I want is like this:

Loop 1

Number : 1 
Class : 20
Level : 20

Loop 2

Number : 2
Class : 21
Level : 41 < this result is from this Class + Level ( before this loop ) = 21 + 20

Loop 3

Number : 3
Class : 22
Level : 63 < this result is from this Class + Level ( before this loop ) = 22 + 41

Loop 4

Number : 4
Class : 23
Level : 86 < this result is from this Class + Level ( before this loop ) = 23 + 63

Loop 5
and so on

Comment: Try to elaborate. It is very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Whatever you're asking, it's most likely possible. Have you started learning JavaScript yet?

Comment: Certainly you can add the previous `Level` to the current `Class` in order to calculate the current `Level`. How to do it depends on the relationship between the data, and the desired output.

Comment: I have been trying since 2 hours ago.. i only can do for number and class but not for level..
how to add now class and level at (before looping)

Comment: @KhenImvu: It would be better if you showed the code you have so far so that people can have a better idea of the result you need.

Comment: @Cookie Monster : http://jsfiddle.net/FcK39/ thats sir.. 
thank you so much .. but problem solved i got answer from developerCK
Sorry if this question is very noob D:

Comment: Nothing wrong with noob questions. Just good idea to show what you've done so far, and where exactly you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var no=1;
var cl=19;
var level =0;
for(var i=0;i<=10;i++){
    alert(no);
    no++;
   cl++;
   alert(cl);
  level = level+cl;
  alert(level);
 }
```

try fildle http://jsfiddle.net/eQeC4/1/

Comment: Ahh finally..Thanks you so much.. this working ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
var buf = 0, firstClass = 19, i = 1, cycleLength = 100;

for(; i < cycleLength; i++) {
    var number = i;
    var Class = firstClass + i;
    var Level = Class + buf;
    buf = Level;
}
```